# Can music be written using scale degree numbers instead of note letters in LilyPond?

Tags: lilypond

Is it possible to refer to notes by scale degree rather than their name in LilyPond? For example instead of `c d e`, set the key to `c` and use `1 2 3`. Or using movable-do solfege syllables (do, ro, re, me, mi...)? Or can those syllables be defined as variables/macros? I'm completely new to LilyPond, and I'm finding it hard to answer this question on my own. I don't think I would use LilyPond if it only works with note letters.

Comment: I do not believe that you'll be able to get the note names as numerals (1,2 etc) -- lilypond syntax requires the note names be be comprised of letters; but you do have complete flexibility in what names get mapped to which notes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can both load [definitions that change the input name of notes](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.12/Documentation/user/lilypond/Writing-pitches#Note-names-in-other-languages) (e.g. the German style definition changes the input syntax for a 'b' to 'h') and apply automatic transpositions (\transpose c e {...}). Between those two features, you should be able to notate anything in any way you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I edited the `define-note-names.scm` file and defined a custom `movabledo` language. Works like a charm!

Comment: It would be interesting if you would post your custom language or a link to it here!